# How to return java response object based on conditional logic in reactive java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Here I have a method where fetchReport is an external call to a vendor API. I want to copy that data to Azure Blob Storage but not if There was an error. If there was an error then I want to return the CustomResponse with the error details. writeToBlob() also returns a CustomResponse. I want to be able to preserve the error message from the external API to give to the consumer.

Is there any way I can use some conditional logic like

```
if response.contains("Failed") -> then return response with error details
else -> write to blob
```

```
    public Flux<CustomResponse> getAndSaveReport(Mono<JsonNode> fetchReport, String reportFilePrefix) {
        Mono<JsonNode> reportMono = fetchReport
                .doOnSuccess(result -> {
                    log.info(Logger.EVENT_UNSPECIFIED, "Successfully retrieved report");
                })
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(objectMapper.convertValue(new CustomResponse("No content"), JsonNode.class)))
                .onErrorResume(BusinessException.class, err -> {
                    log.error(Logger.EVENT_FAILURE, "Failed to retrieve report");
                    JsonNode errJson = null;
                    CustomResponse apiResponse = new CustomResponse();
                    apiResponse.setStatus("Failed");
                    apiResponse.setMessage("Error message: " + err.getMessage());
                    apiResponse.setType(reportFilePrefix);
                    errJson = objectMapper.convertValue(apiResponse, JsonNode.class);
                    return Mono.just(errJson);
                });

        return writeToBlob(reportMono.flux(), reportFilePrefix).flux();
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why not `doOnError`

Comment: Now if only you could put that code in the `map` or `doOnSuccess` method, wouldn't that be convinient.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what `fetchReport` returns but the code could be simplified by applying `flatMap`. Also, not sure why are you using `flux()` everywhere when only one signal is passed - you can use `Mono` instead.

```
public Mono<CustomResponse> getAndSaveReport(Mono<JsonNode> fetchReport, String reportFilePrefix) {
    return fetchReport
            .flatMap(result -> {
                if (result.response.contains("Failed")) {
                    // error handling
                    return Mono.just(errorResponse);
                } else {
                    return writeToBlob(result.report, reportFilePrefix)
                }
            });
}
```